# f is surjective $\iff$ $g_1 \circ f = g_2 \circ f \to g_1 = g_2 $

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I was given a task to prove the following

> f is surjective $\iff$ $g_1 \circ f = g_2 \circ f \to g_1 = g_2 $

But I do not completely understand the task. Could you please give some clarification ?

I figured out that I do not understand how to prove statements in the form

> A if and only if B implies C

Is it the correct way of proof?
Suppose A is true and from there get that B is also true.
Then suppose that B is true and from there get that A is true.

Comment: You had posted the same question (in a different formulation though) about one week ago. I am not sure if the posting is still valid, but I gave you a thorough answer there. I will try to reproduce the same answer over here as well, so take a look.

Comment: @ΑΘΩ I deleted my profile, so I think the question was deleted either. Thanks, I will wait for your answer.

Comment: Here you should interpret it with parenthesis: $A\iff (B\implies C)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a map $f \colon A \to B$. The goal is to show $f$ is surjective if and only if for any pair of maps $g, h \colon B \to M$ the relation $g \circ f=h \circ f$ entails the equality $g=h$ (in brief, a map $f$ exhibiting this property is said to be *right-cancellable*, as it can be cancelled whenever it occurs as the right factor of two equal compositions).

1. The easy implication: assume that $f$ is surjective and that $g, h \colon B \to M$ are such that $g \circ f=h \circ f$. This means that $g(f(x))=h(f(x))$ is valid for any $x \in A$ and -- since by virtue of the surjectivity of $f$ any element $y \in B$ can be expressed as $y=f(x)$ for a certain $x \in A$ -- this leads to $g(y)=h(y)$ for any $y \in B$. Since the two maps $g$ and $h$ coincide in terms of domains of definition, codomain and map the same arguments into the same images, they are equal.
2. The less simple implication: assume by contradiction there exists a map $f$ which is right-cancellable however *not* surjective. This means that $\mathrm{Im}f=f[A] \subset B$ (strict inclusion) and thus we can fix a certain $a \in B \setminus f[A]$. Consider the following maps:
   $$\begin{align*}
   g, h \colon B &\to \{\varnothing, \{\varnothing\}\}\\
   g(y)&=\varnothing\\
   h(y)&=\begin{cases}
   \varnothing, &y \in f[A]\\
   \{\varnothing\}, &y \in B \setminus f[A].
   \end{cases}
   \end{align*}$$
   It is clear that $g \circ f=h \circ f$, since for any $x \in A$ we have by definition $g(f(x))=h(f(x))=\varnothing$, however $g \neq h$, since $g(a)=\varnothing \neq \{\varnothing\}=h(a)$ ($\{\varnothing\}$ is a singleton containing the only element $\varnothing$, so in any case it isn't empty). This means that the map $f$ actually fails to be right-cancellable, contradicting our hypothesis. It follows that $f$ is necessarily surjective.

---

As a minor remark on method, a more direct way to establish the second implication is by rendering it through contraposition into the equivalent statement: "a non-surjective map is not right-cancellable". Essentially that is what the above argument does: under the assumption that $f$ is not surjective it exhibits an explicit pair of distinct maps which nevertheless yield equal compositions when composed with $f$ on the left.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer. But why does the $g(f(x))=h(f(x))$. They have same domain, but since g can only be mapped to 1 element, while h can be mapped to 2 elements doesn't it mean that they have the different codomains, therefore $g(f(x)) \neq h(f(x))$

Comment: @Rustem Sadykov You are most likely confusing the notion of *image set* (some call it range, although I dislike that term) with that of *codomain*. A map is defined as a triplet $f=(A, F, B)$, where $A$ is the domain of definition, $B$ is the codomain and $F \subseteq A \times B$ is a *functional* relation (the one describing $f$), which to *any* element of $A$ assigns a *unique* element of $B$. It may very well be that the image set $f[A]$ is a *proper* subset of $B$, in the case of a non-surjective $f$: indeed, not every element of $B$ occurs as an image of $f$ *(to be cont.)*

Comment: @Rustem Sadykov *(cont.)* However, this doesn't change at all the fact that the codomain of $f$ is $B$! This applies in particular to the map $g$ defined in the answer above. $g$ is not surjective, $h$ on the other hand is however regardless of that by definition they have the same codomain. The moment you see the syntax $f \colon A \to B$, that signifies that $A$ is the definition domain of $f$ and $B$ is its codomain. Hope this helps to clarify things!

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $g_1\ne g_2$. Then for some $x$ we have $g_1(x)\ne g_2(x)$. So if $f$ was surjective then $x=f(y)$ for some $y$. But then $ g_1\circ f(y)\ne g_2\circ f(y)$ and $g_1\circ f \ne g_2\circ f$. Conversely if $g_1\circ f\ne g_2\circ f$ then for some $y$ we have $g_1(f(y))\ne g_2(f(y))$ so $ g_1\ne g_2$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I figured out what I do not understand in this task. I do not understand how to prove statement that involves iff and if, then. Could you please explain, what is the algorithm to prove such statements. I proved that $g_1 \circ f = g_2 \circ f \to g_1 = g_2$. What do I do next ?

Comment: "A iff B" means "A is true if and only if B is true". The way to prove it is first assume that A is true and prove B and then assume that B is true and prove A. equivalently you can first assume that A is false and prove that B is also false, a then assume that B is false and prove that A is false.